# Fake Date object in Javascript test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I use [buster.js](http://busterjs.org/) and I want to test a function returning the age of a person from her year of birth. My test look like this:

```
"Should get correct age from year": function () {
    assert(getAgeFromYear(1990) === 22);
}
```

This will only stay green until the end of 2012. How can I fake the date object in buster.js so that it will be valid in the next years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function `getAgeFromYearDate(int, Date)` and test that. Then make a function `getAgeFromYear(int)` which uses the current Date. That method will look like this:

```
function getAgeFromYear(year) {
    return getAgeFromYearDate(year, new Date());
}
```

If `getAgeFromYearDate` works correctly, you can assume that `getAgeFromYear` works correctly.

Comment: Instead of adding a new function, just modify `getAgeFromYear` so it can optionally take a 'now' Date instance as the second parameter.